# How to store values in a PHP array as multiple records in MySQL

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have created a PHP function to insert data into a MySQL table. One of the values passed into the function is an array. The array contains unique values only. When I run the script it saves one record to the table with the field corresponding to the array storing all the array values.

This is my function which is in a separate class file:

```
public function importTest($val1,$valArray,$val3){

    try {

        $stm = $this->dbSt->prepare('INSERT INTO table (val1,valArray,val3) VALUES (:val1,:valArray,:val3)');

        $stm->bindParam(':val1',$val1);
        $stm->bindParam(':valArray',$valArray);
        $stm->bindParam(':val3',$val3);

        if($stm->execute()){

            return true;
        }

    }catch (PDOException $e) {

        echo $e->getMessage();
    }


    return false;

}
```

Setting `$test` and echoing to the screen for testing purposes. This displays all unique values in the array which is what I am looking for.:

```
$test = implode("<br />", (array_keys($array_unique_guests)));

echo 'TEST:<br /> '.$test.' <br />';  // Displays all unique values
echo '<br /><br />';
```

This is where I am calling the function:

```
$importTest = $statsDao->importTest($getSites[$x]['site_id'],$test,$updateDate);
```

I am using a for loop to get values for `$getSites` which calls another function.

I need all the values being echoed to the screen above as $test to be saved as new records in the table. Instead they are all being added in one record.

I would like to insert as many rows as there are values in the array. This number will change, but for example, if there are 10 values in the array, there should be 10 records added to the table, along with a date and another field. Basically, I am trying to retrieve all the values in the array and create a new record for each one when the script runs.

I hope this is clear. I've been stuck on this for a while and hoping someone can help!

Thanks!

Comment: To start your passing in `$test` which is a string, so make sure you pass the array of values you want to store.

Comment: So basically you trying to generate something like  `INSERT INTO ... VALUES(<value>),(<value>)[, ...]` which can insert multiple records in MYSQL..

Comment: If I understood, you want to loop through the array, each element in the array - add a row to the database with that value?

Comment: Yes, that's correct Jaquarh - add a row to the table with each element in the array.  I'm not sure how to pass in the array instead of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the array to the function, not an imploded string, and then use a  loop in the function.

```
public function importTest($val1,$valArray,$val3){

    try {

        $stm = $this->dbSt->prepare('INSERT INTO table (val1,valArray,val3) VALUES (:val1,:val2,:val3)');

        $stm->bindParam(':val1',$val1);
        $stm->bindParam(':val2',$val2);
        $stm->bindParam(':val3',$val3);

        foreach ($valArray as $val2) {
            $stm->execute();
        }
    }catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You pass the array directly with:

```
$statsDao->importTest($getSites[$x]['site_id'], array_keys($array_unique_guests), $updateDate);
```

Comment: `$stm->bindParam(':val2',$val2);` will result in a notice. .where is `$val2` defined?

Comment: It's in the `for` loop. `bindParam` binds a reference, so you can assign it later.

Comment: Any valid loop will do, I edited it to be more generic

Comment: "It's in the for loop. bindParam binds a reference, so you can assign it later" Indeed `public bool PDOStatement::bindParam ( mixed $parameter , mixed &$variable [, int $data_type = PDO::PARAM_STR [, int $length [, mixed $driver_options ]]] )` now i see didn't notice it before `&$variable` which is indeed a reference

Comment: That's the difference between `bindParam` and `bindVal`.

Comment: Barmar, I have tried this and it works perfectly!  Thanks for the assistance.  i am trying to give this a vote, but i am unable to because my score isn't high enough yet.   I appreciate your help.  :)

Answer (score 0):

So far I could guess from the title,

```
 $inser = "INSERT INTO table_name(id,name,pass) VALUES";
    $valuearray = array( // the array composed of values that you have prepared
          [  
            "id"  => 1,
            "name" => "John Due",
            "pass" => "123456"
          ],
          [  
            "id"  => 2,
            "name" => "Jonathan",
            "pass" => "123456"
          ],
          [  
            "id"   => 3,
            "name" => "Jonny",
            "pass" => "123456"
          ]
    ); 
    foreach($valuearray as $val)
    {
      $inser .= "('".$val['id']."','".$val['name']."','".$val['pass']."')";
    }
    echo $inser;
```

Comment: The original code uses a prepared statement, which protects against SQL injection. Why are you downgrading to variable concatenation? Also, `$valArray` is just for the second column, the other two columns come from `$val1` and `$val2`, they're the same in every row.